# Java: open stream to device for input and output

Tags: java, stream

I need to interact with a small label printer (via a form of ESC/P) from java, on a linux environment. The printer is available as character device at `/dev/usb/lp0`.

Sending data works very well:

```
FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/lp0");
BufferedOutputStream lp0out = new BufferendOutputStream(oStream);
byte[] data = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40}; // ESC, @  = initialise printer
lp0out.write(data);
```

Now to interrogate the printer status, I also need to read its response to a particular command. How do I open a device in input- and output-mode? Do I need to close the outputstream after sending the request, then open the device for input?

Comment: Have you tried just opening a FileIntputStream on the same device in a sepearate thread?

Comment: If you're sure there will be input generated, you can do it on the same thread, even: open both streams, write output, then read input.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?